# Существенны ли мягкий и твердый знаки на письме?

Tags: выбор-слова

Я называю символ существенным в слове, если его удаление приведет к новому слову. Например, если удалить из слова "из" букву "з", я получу другое слово "и", т.е. буква "з" существенна в слове "из".

Я называю букву существенной, если существует слово (русского языка), в котором она существенна.

Существенен ли мягкий знак (ь)? Если да, приведите пожалуйста пример, где его удаление приведен к образованию нового слова. Аналогично для твердого знака.

Comment: _Другое_ слово обязано существовать в языке?

Comment: @Dmitry конечно. Иначе вопрос тривиален

Comment: Уголь - угол, конь - кон, пыль - пыл, быль - был, рожь - [много] рож.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, оба знака существенны.

Мягкий:

> Вонь - Вон
>   Семья - Семя

Твердый:

> Съесть - Сесть

Answer (score 2):

Палатализация согласных - неотъемлемая часть русской фонетики. То, о чём вы спрашиваете, [называется](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) `минимальными парами` и в случае мягких и твёрдых согласных таких пар в русском языке очень много. Вот [цитата](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) из википедии:

> Существует большое число минимальных пар, различающихся по
>   мягкости/твёрдости согласных, в частности, в русском языке: [н]ос
>   слушать «нос» — [н’]ос «нёс»; бы[т] «быт» — бы[т’] «быть»; пы[л] «пыл»
>   — пы[л’] «пыль».

Кроме того, я не могу отметить, что отсутствие минимальной пары не означало бы само по себе "несущественность" - даже если нет "мягкого" или "твёрдого" аналога - это не значит, что можно будет произнести (или написать) иначе - и вас поймут.

Comment: Нет, я спрашивал не совсем об этом. Меня не интересует **замена** одной буквы на другую, меня интересует возможность **убрать** из слова букву так, чтобы после удаление этой буквы слово не совпадало с другим. 
Оказалось, что это невозможно в общем случае для ь и ъ.

Дело в том, что изъятие буквы помогло бы, например, сократить алфавит и сжать текст.